# Create new column via boolean indexing while using two arrays of different size and index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. Both of different sizes and of different indexes. However they have two columns of the same name: 'Start' and 'Stop'. I need to check every row in A to see if B's Start and Stop are between the Start and Stop in A. Here is a diagram:

AStart --- BStart BStop --- AStop

Upon determining if that is true, I need to increment a column in A called 'Inside' by 1, and go on to the next row in B and perform the same test.

I am primarily getting hung up on the issue of combining the complicated boolean test with the task of: for every row in A, test every row in B

I have tried using the .loc function and also using some sort of apply method, but I think I am just missing something for the .loc function.

For the below code, I get a Value Error saying that I can only compare identically-labeled Series objects but I have tried dropping the indices and also using .value notation to try and get around that, but that hasn't worked.

```
# I have tried:
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 A.loc[(A.Start <= B.Start) & (B.Stop <= A.Stop), 'Inside'] += 1

#----------
#Ideally
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,5], [4,7]], index=['Gene Z', 'Gene X'], columns = ['Start', 'Stop'])
A


  #      Start  Stop
#Gene Z      1     5
#Gene X      4     7

B = pd.DataFrame([[2,4], [4,9]], index=['Obj 1', 'Obj 2'], columns = ['Start', 'Stop']) 
B

#         Start  Stop
#Obj 1      2     4
#Obj 2      4     9

# Output:
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,1], [4,7,np.nan]], index=['Gene Z', 'Gene X'], columns = ['Start', 'Stop', 'Inside'])
A

  #      Start  Stop Inside
 #Gene Z      1     5   1
 #Gene X      4     7   np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
A['Inside'] = A.apply(lambda x: B[(B['Start'] >= x['Start']) & (B['Stop'] <= x['Stop'])]['Start'].count(), axis=1)
```

This will go through all of the rows in A and for each one, will go through the rows in B where the condition is met and count those rows.

Output:

```
        Start   Stop    Inside
Gene Z      1      5         1
Gene X      4      7         0
```

Comment: What purpose does the last ['Start'] serve? I am having trouble understanding its use.

Additionally, if I wanted to later have another function that would do some sort of division between the numbers, say ((Start/Stop) + 1) how could I do that, because .count() would fail to work?

Comment: the last ['Start'] makes it so that count() takes the count of a series and returns a number, rather than a number per column in the dataframe. If you'd like to do another operation that does not involve counting, change the lambda function to divide Start/Stop and add 1 and it will apply that to each row in the dataframe

Comment: Could you type out this second example please, with the same conditionals? It would be useful because I am having trouble extending this paradigm into other uses. I apologize for being so dense. 

I also was able to get the same result from your usage if I used ['Stop'] at the end, so I am unsure why we should prefer one over the other.

Comment: just to confirm - you want to add a column that divides stop/start + 1?
this would be
```A.apply(lambda x: x['Start']/x['Stop'] +1)```
adding ['Stop'] instead of ['Start'] to the first example wouldn't change anything; just changes the column we are counting but keeps the results the same

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes I would like to perform that step, but with the conditionals as well. Because it appears that you were subsetting B in order to make the conditionals work with the lambda expression, but meshing the two is proving to be difficult

Comment: can you explain this more in detail? what condition would you want the division to occur under/not work under?

Comment: I would like for the division to take place under the condition that used at the beginning: 

`B[(B['Start'] >= x['Start']) & (B['Stop'] <= x['Stop'])]`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but this may work 

```A.apply(lambda x: B[(B['Start'] >= x['Start']) & (B['Stop'] <= x['Stop'])].apply(lambda y : (y['Start'] / y['Stop']) +1), axis=1)
```
Also, if my first solution solved your question, please mark the question as solved

Comment: Your initial answer solves my question, but it seems to me that there must be a better way if ['Start'] or ['Stop'] can be interchangeable in terms of counting

Comment: in terms of them being interchangeable, that just forces count() to return 1 number instead of a row with two identical numbers (counting each column instead of just 1)